# Not getting coolant in the engine

Tags: overheating, pontiac, firebird

2001 Pontiac firebird v6 not getting coolant to the engine. The heater doesn't get warm.

I've taken out the thermostat. *[System]* builds up pressure in the radiator and I've found no leaks anywhere

Comment: Welcome to the stack. Could you add anything you've tried for debugging so far? Also, you chose the tag "overheating" but say that no coolant is getting into the motor (via your title), what makes you assume that it's not getting coolant?

Comment: Because it heats up really quick and the heater doesn't get warm and it doesn't look like it flows in the radiator don't have any leaks from the water pump or any noises

Comment: Ok. And when you say you've taken the thermostat out, you mean you tested it with the thermostat out and it's still overheating?

Comment: Yes I took it out to see if that was staying closed

Comment: Have you checked the health of the hoses or done a pressure test?

Comment: The hoses didn't look like they were collapsing and it gets so much pressure built up on its own lol

Comment: I checked the hoses they didn't look like they were collapsing and it is building up plenty of pressure on its own.lol

Comment: Sorry trying to figure out how this works first time using

Comment: No worries. Is there a lot of pressure on the top and bottom radiator hose? If there's pressure in just one hose then that would indicate a blockage in the *radiator* whereas both hoses would indicate something else.

Comment: And before this started happening I don't think it really got hot enough to blow a head gasket

Comment: Oh, dumb oversight in my part (face palm) have you checked the pump to make sure that's not the problem...?

Comment: I will check that I did notice the top hose heated up when the bottom wasn't and that was with the thermostat out

Comment: How would I know if the pump was working wouldn't it be leaking or making noise like the bearing going out

Comment: Maybe, but I lean away from that since you are getting hot coolant moving. Personally I'm leaning toward radiator blockage or head gasket damage. Also, is there more pressure in the top hose than the bottom?

Comment: I will find out and get back with you ty

Comment: I've got to admit that I don't really understand the body of this question either before or after the edit. Some complete sentences with a clear ordering of steps and results would help immensely.

Comment: Coolant expands enough to seem like "pressure" in the system.  Definitely replace the thermostat properly and count on the water pump impeller spinning too easily when you take the belt off the pulley(internal). Replace the water pump and hope the actual pressure doesn't bust any hoses or the radiator.  If the internals were sitting in bad coolant/water for a long time, the pump is the first thing to corrode. The radiator could be close behind(if it isn't too weakened now) Good Luck, please post your results. Cheers!